# How do I get rid of unwanted immigrants?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've just gotten a large number of immigrants, most of whom I don't want, and I would like to get rid of them. I have a small room set up to flood with water, but short of giving those dwarfs I want to kill a bedroom in there I'm not sure how to get them to stay in there. So, basically, what is a good method to order a specific group of dwarfs to stay in this room so I can drown them?

Game version is 40d.

Comment: I think I might make a squad of military dwarves and create a barracks for them to sit in in that killroom.

Comment: What is wrong with you!?!? Those dwarves trekked all the way from the Moutainhome to come help you, and you want to repay them with a watery death!? You could at least use a cave in or something more dwarvish, geez.

Comment: @antony.trupe: when in doubt use magma.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- Create a squad for them.
- Create a point in the notes menu.
- Station squad at that point.
- Pull lever.

Comment: Thanks, I've just done this and happily executed those useless migrants :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, won't killing all those migrants upset your other dwarves and lower moral in the fortress?

Comment: @theJollySin: If they didn't met with your dwarfs before (don't have relationships) and don't see how they are dying - no.

Answer (score 4):

You can also assign a burrow, and then assign the migrants to the burrow. The dwarves will all cluster into the space, allowing you to pull the lever and handle the problem all at once. (Assuming more than 10 dwarves).

Burrows have the additional benefit of being reusable each time a new migrant wave pops onto the map. Just assign the new guys to it and repeat.

Comment: A note on burrows: dwarves assigned to a burrow that does not contain one of its needs (food, drink, etc.) will leave the burrow when they have to fulfill that need. So there's no guarantee they'll all be in there at once, but it often works out that way.

Comment: Migrants don't enter the map hungry or thirsty though, so as long as you're prompt with your drowning chamber, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I'm using 40d at the moment, and I don't think it has the burrow capability, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @xavieran -- ya should mention that in your question next time! ;P

Answer (score 4):

There is an easier way, though less Fun!, that makesk them die in a useful manner. Give them all weapons, and make them stay outside. Set them to train constantly if you want. Then wait for the next invasion. They should slow down the invasion for a little bit, allowing your military more time to respond.

Alternatively, just lock them in a room without food.

While less classic, both of these can be done without the use of magma, in case you haven't reached it yet, or don't want to make large alterations to your fort.