# How to make dwarves stay indoor in dwarf fortress 2010

Tags: dwarf-fortress

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do I get rid of unwanted immigrants?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-do-i-get-rid-of-unwanted-immigrants)
>   [How do I get my dwarfs inside?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3597/how-do-i-get-my-dwarfs-inside)

Hi,
I know that in DF 40d, there was a way to tell the dwarves to stay indoor. Is there any way to do that in 2010... It's quite useful when there are goblins attacks.

Comment: @LessPop how do you figure? The intent of the question is not even similar.

Comment: Yeah, I misread the question. Consider the close vote 'retracted'. :/

Comment: Definite duplicate of [How do I get my dwarfs inside?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3597/how-do-i-get-my-dwarfs-inside).

Comment: @C.Ross -- Now that, I agree with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you need to familiarize yourself with burrows and military alerts.

https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Burrows

The key is to make a burrow that is completely behind your defensive perimeter. Then, you can access the military alerts screen (Default: m - a) and set things up to restrict civilians to a particular burrow.

At that point, whenever you change the alert, when the sieges and ambushes come around, your civilians will not leave the safety of their burrow.

https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Scheduling

Comment: Ok, so I need to have a custom burrow with my whole indoor in order to do that... Thanks man.